# Flattened JSON Repeating Columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having an issue currently with pulling from an API, getting a JSON dict, then flattening it, and placing it into a dataframe.

The data is structured like this from the json:

```
X1_0, X2_0, X3_0 ... X1_1, X2_1, X2_1, ... X1_2, X2_2, X2_3
```

and when I flatten it and place into a dataframe I get each flattened key as an individual column header rather than all combined since they have they _#.

So rather than getting something that's shape is 22 x 6 I get something that would be like 1 x 130.

I'm basically just interested in getting the shape of the dataframe correct but I'm not sure how I should fix it, and whether it should be done before flattening or after?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why don't you change your flattening code to produce a JSON array with six items `[X1, X2, X3, X4, X5...]`?

Comment: I just used the 6 as an example but in reality when the input changes (in this case lat/long for Bing Maps API), the output will change and could be more/less than 6 items. So a static fix like setting the array to six items wouldn't really work because sometimes the api may return 4, 8, or even 100.

I'm thinking now the best option might be to remove the identifying number from the columns since that seems to be the only reason they're not stacking

Answer (score 0):

Try to strip the `_#` from the keys. My guess is that they are added in the flattening step, so it should be easy to get rid of them.

Now you will get several values per key. Fix this by creating a list of JSON objects where each contains all the values for each key with the same `_#`.